# why "WP Search Suggest" plugin search only product data instead of all?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using this WordPress plugin which link is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-search-suggest/

In this plugin there is a method called `ajax_response` and has a code like that:

```
$query_args = apply_filters( 'wpss_search_query_args', array(
    's'           => $s,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
), $s );

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

now I use `print_r($query)` to check which `post_type` is calling. Now I see its only calling `post_type = 'product'` :(

I need to search page or post as well.

How can I do this?

Update: The form has the id attribute already:

[image]

Comment: Please check search field id="s" and/or name="s" first

Comment: Yes those attributes are already added.